# Angular 4 - managing state

Tags: angular, state

I am developing an Angular 4 app that will need to save the navigation state such that when the user navigates away from the app to another non-Angular web app and then back again it should re-display the last place where he left off.

I am looking at an established pattern to follow to do this.  So far I am investigating Redux with Angular, is this the best solution to do something like the above?

Comment: actually I don't think redux will handle this for you. In order to save the page for when they come back, you will want to save the url in localstorage or even on the server. Redux is for managing state as they use your application.

Comment: thanks!  I am using Redux/ngrx as well but you are right, I need to use localstorage for this, particularly session storage works well for my purpose.